# spinning wheel?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a counter in flash. The effect is like a slot machine, with one column, that contains two sprites with numbers in them (9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). I'm checking the y-position for each of them and if they goes less than a certain y-value, then I move that down below the other one so it becomes continusly. Anyway - I have a timer that runs every 100ms and each time it fires it updates a value by 1. I then want to make the numbers scroll to that position, but it all goes to fast, so it keeps jumping back and forth instead = no seamless loop.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE DESCRIPTION**

The value is not increment by only 1, instead it will be increment by "inpValue" in "tick". I will have x number of tickers that count up to a value that increment (every time when my timer fires, for example every 100ms), for example the value can be "1.03", and next time the timer fire it can be something like "1.14". I split this number into three "columns"=tickers and each ticker will have it value;
ticker1: 1
ticker2: 1
ticker3: 4

When ticker3 get next "0"-value = 10, ticker2 should update to "2" and so on.
The problem is to make the numbers scroll so if the number was "4" the first time, and next time it is "2", it should actually scroll through all the numbers between that and so on, and not jump back up with that row.

So if i for example stop the tickers at value "1.14", that should be the value the tickers stop at.

**EDIT: CODE**

```
package gui {
import flash.events.Event;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.easing.Linear;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Ticker extends Sprite {

    public var windowBg_mc:MovieClip;

    private var _stepValue:int = 0;

    public var row1:MovieClip;
    public var row2:MovieClip;
    private var _activeRow:MovieClip;

    public var stopBtn:MovieClip;

    public function Ticker() {
        init(0);
    }

    private function init(val:int):void{

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateConnection);

        _stepValue = val;

        TweenMax.to(row2, 0, {tint: 0xff0000});

        _activeRow = row1;

        var yMoveTarget_num:Number = -(Number(_stepValue) * 34);

        TweenLite.to(_activeRow, 5, {y: yMoveTarget_num, ease: Linear.easeNone});

        updateConnection(null);
    }

    private function updateConnection(e:Event):void{

        if(_activeRow.y <= -342){
            _activeRow.y = 340;
            if( _activeRow == row1 ){
                _activeRow = row2;
            }else{
                _activeRow = row1;
            }
        }

        if( _activeRow == row1 ){
            row2.y = row1.y + 340;
        }else{
            row1.y = row2.y + 340;
        }

    }

    public function tick(inpValue:int):void{

        if(_stepValue == inpValue) return;

        var oldValue : int = _stepValue;
        _stepValue = inpValue;

        if( _stepValue < oldValue ){
            //target must be change here
        }

        var yMoveTarget_num:Number = -(Number(_stepValue) * 34);
        TweenLite.to(_activeRow, .4, {y: yMoveTarget_num, ease: Linear.easeIn});
    }

}
}
```

And "tick" is the method that gets called every 100ms.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've written so far?

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is, do you have swf somewhere to look at?

Comment: Here is where you can download the swf using 1000ms: http://temp-share.com/show/Pf3Yp88q2

And here is the 100ms (buggy version) file: http://temp-share.com/show/dPf356ipW

Comment: You must adjust the `TweenLite.to` duration (.3). BTW  _activeRow.y = 340 should probably `_activeRow.y += (306 + 340)` which is the movie clip height I think.

Comment: the speed for tweenlite fixes that.. the thing is i want "tick" to be able to take a parameter, like "val" which is something between 0-9. that value for one call can first be say 4, and next time 2. then i want the numbers to scroll through the numbers between those two. so for going between 4 to 2, there are actually 8 steps. otherwise this wont reflect the whole number im counting up to. I update my question again to be more clear...